# In apex, what data structure do I use to pass a list of IDs to a SOQL where clause?

Tags: apex, soql

My method is being passed a list of objects.  I want to use the object IDs in a where clause to retrieve a list of related objects. Representing this scenario abstractly:

```
`public methodname (List<inputObject> inputObjects) {
       List<otherOBject> otherObjects = new List <otherObject>;

       otherObjects = [select field1, field2, ... fieldn from otherObjects where lookupfield in (:inputObjects)];
       ...
 }`
```

In this case `otherObject.lookupfield` is a lookup to `inputObject`, so there is a relationship. Is apex/SOQL smart enough to use `inputObject.ID` to qualify this query? Or can I pass an array of Ids that I build from `inputObjects`? Or is there some other collection structure I should use for this filter?

Answer (score 2):

For lookup fields, you can pass in a `List<sObject>` as a filter:

```
otherObject[] otherObjects = [SELECT field1, ... from otherObject WHERE lookup__c = :inputObjects];
```

Note that for Apex, `=` and `in` are synonyms if the bound parameter is a `List` (of `sObject`, `Id`, etc).

Comment: so it's easier than I thought -- thanks for the info -- can't wait to try it out.